# Ansible Task seems to miss some library

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

i'm currently playing with Ansible (To get more familiar) but i'm encountering some issue and i'm not sure on how to fix it.

This is the machine where i'm running the script (is a gns3 docker):

```
root@NetworkAutomation-1:~# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

This is the python versions :

```
root@NetworkAutomation-1:~# pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

P3:

```
root@NetworkAutomation-1:~# pip3 --version
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Ansible:

```
root@NetworkAutomation-1:~# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /root/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) [GCC 7.5.0]
```

This is the script in yaml:

````
---
 - name: "Manage Gns3 Topology"
   hosts: R1
   gather_facts : false
   connection: local

   vars:
    cli:
      username:cisco
      password:cisco
      transport:cli

   tasks:
     - name : enable ospf
       ios_config:
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        authorize: yes
        parents: router ospf 1
        lines:
          - network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0

       register: print_output

     - debug: var=print_output```
````

And this is the error that i'm getting

````
TASK [enable ospf] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/firstplaybook.yml:14
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 146, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 645, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/ios.py", line 48, in run
    provider = load_provider(ios_provider_spec, self._task.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils/network/common/utils.py", line 440, in load_provider
    provider[key] = args[key]
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
fatal: [R1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}```
````

Already thank you for your time and effort.

---

as suggested i tried to update to Python 3 (i did unistall the ansible on p2 and ran a clean installation wiht pip3 install ansible), but i'm getting more or less the same issue, but now is calling for p3 rather than p2.

```
TASK [enable ospf] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/firstplaybook.yml:14
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 146, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 654, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/ios.py", line 48, in run
    provider = load_provider(ios_provider_spec, self._task.args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils/network/common/utils.py", line 446, in load_provider
    provider[key] = None
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
fatal: [R1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Comment: you should probably be running ansible from python3 on the NetworkAutomation machine

Comment: Module `ios_config` (Manage Cisco IOS configuration sections) should configure Ubuntu (connection: local)?

Comment: i tried to run python3 as suggested but still got the same problem

``` root@NetworkAutomation-1:~# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.10
  config file = /root/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.3 (default, May 14 2020, 20:11:43) [GCC 7.5.0]
root@NetworkAutomation-1:~# ^C
root@NetworkAutomation-1:~# ```

Answer (score 0):

So thank to one of my friend (that is experienced with coding) i managed to understand that the problem was in the script itself, what i still do not understand is why. Since both the course i'm following and the ansible doc do provide the same exact example.

Here is what i've done

````
   hosts: R1
   gather_facts : false
   connection: local

#   vars:
#    cli:
#      username:cisco
#      password:cisco
#      transport:cli

   tasks:
     - name : enable ospf
       ios_config:
        username: cisco
        username: cisco
#        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        authorize: yes
        parents: router ospf 1
        lines:
          - network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0

       register: print_output

     - debug: var=print_output```

so it seems that is having problems with the variable that i'm using for the authentication, if anyone knows why please let me know.
````